# How should I specify type of children for styled-components React Native component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

If I create a styled component like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled(View)``;
```

and try to use it and pass children to it, I get this TyepScript error:

> Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick,
>   "style" | "hitSlop" | "onLayout" | "pointerEvents" |
>   "removeClippedSubviews" | "testID" | "nativeID" | ... 38 more ... |
>   "ref"> & Partial<...>, "style" | ... 44 more ... | "ref"> & { ...; } &
>   { ...; }'.

unless I explicitly define the children property's type:

```
const Wrapper = styled(View)<{ children?: React.ReactNode }>``;
```

Is there a better way or is this what I'm supposed to do? It seems like doing this for every single component is repetitive and should have a better way.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of being annoyed by this and finally deciding to ask on StackOverflow... as soon as I do I find that a PR has been merged less than two hours ago to fix this exact issue:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/32843

In 4.1.9 of styled-components, the children property type is automatically added to all components.